# how to fix nifti image dimension to match?

Tags: itk, nifti

i can’t upload the segmentation image with the main image 
i got the segmented image  after the treatment (output test )
 where the dimensions of main image and segmented are not the same
but I want to combine main image with segmented image
any solution please to match the segmentated image with the main image?

i tried to match the message displayed is "the size of segmentation image does not match with main image images must have the same dimensions"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOFHh.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can need to resample the image into the same size as the original image - assuming your segmentation is in the same origin as the input image this function should do that.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

def resample_image(input_img, input_seg,  is_label=False):
    dimension = 3

    original_spacing = itk_image.GetSpacing()
    original_size = itk_image.GetSize()

    resample = sitk.ResampleImageFilter()
    resample.SetOutputSpacing(original_spacing)
    resample.SetSize(out_size)
    resample.SetOutputDirection(input_img.GetDirection())
    resample.SetOutputOrigin(input_img.GetOrigin())
    resample.SetTransform(sitk.Transform(dimension, sitk.sitkIdentity))
    resample.SetDefaultPixelValue(input_img.GetPixelIDValue())

    if is_label:
        resample.SetInterpolator(sitk.sitkNearestNeighbor)
    else:
        resample.SetInterpolator(sitk.sitkBSpline)

    return resample.Execute(itk_image)
```